# OpenCV nearest neighbour interpolation creates pixels not present in original image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have an image A. The goal is to downsize it to an image, such that the dimensions of the image are smaller, but no pixel in the new image contains a value not present in the original. In other words, if $p \in A'$ then $p \in A$.

I tried doing this in python as follows:

```
resized = cv2.resize(old_img, (1024, 1024), 0, 0, cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

However, when the input is a binary image (old_img contains only black and white pixels), the resulting image contains grey values (values not equal to 0 or 255).

Is this a bug in the implementation? It's a hard requirement for me that no pixel ends up with a non original value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe it should be

```
resized = cv2.resize(old_img, (1024, 1024), 0, 0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Note the `interpolation = ...` as part of the 3rd argument.

See [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d)